# TabHost from Fragments and GoogleMap

Tags: android, fragment, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

I have old TabActivity, it is depreacted now.

I want change it to new TabHost using Fragment.

I need put two tabs: map and list.

Any idea, how can I do this?